# How to get methods declared in vue inside swiper events

Tags: javascript, vue.js, swiper.js, vue-ssr

How to get methods declared in vue inside swiper events?

```
export default {
    data() {
       let obj = {
           swiperOption: {
               ...
               on: {
                init: function () {
                    //need call someMethod in this place
                }
            }
        };
        return obj;
    }
    methods: {
        someMethod (){}
    }
}
```

Now i use

```
const vue = this
```

but i think, it's not good way

Comment: I recommend reading the documentation on the various methods and attributes of a `vue` component. One major flaw I see here is that you're putting methods where there shouldn't be any (inside `data()`).

Comment: Do you have any specific use case to put a method inside `data()`?

Answer (score 0):

`data()` method is not designed to create complex objects with methods. You can just create an empty variable in `data()` method, then fill it with your object in `created` hook or `mounted` hook. You'll be able to access the component via `this` variable if use arrow-function for `init` method inside your object.